# IKVMC dll in Unity TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, java, unity-container, ikvm, typeloadexception

I want to create a DLL from a JAR for use in Unity.
I create a jar file using JavaSE-1.7, then I create the dll from it using ikvmc v7.2.4630.5
When I use this dll in a new C# Windows application it works fine without any exceptions or errors, but when I use it in Unity it also works even though I'm getting the following TypeLoadException:

```
Could not load type 'java.util.Date' from assembly IKVM.OpenJDK.Core
```

But although this works, Unity won't export or build my project due to this exception. How can I get around this?

**EDIT:** Ok the only way I can get this to work is if I use JRE 1.5 and an older version of IKVM like 0.28 which doesn't solve my problem because some functionality from JRE 1.7 is not supported in JRE 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Despite this is an old question, I leave some advices for future reference:

- try to use the last version of IKVM (8.0 at time of writing).
- Go to: Edit -> Project Settings -> Player. Under Other settings for PC / Mac change the API Compability Level from ".NET 2.0 Subset" to ".NET 2.0". Recompile.
- Copy all of the DLLs provided with IKVM inside the Assets folder of your project (NOT in a subfolder).
- All of the Java versions are supported (even Java 8, see [Release Notes](http://weblog.ikvm.net/)).

Comment: This worked just fine for me using Java 7 and IKVM 7.2 (although with a very simple DLL, I will try to use the real Java project I intend to).